# Transition between UIViewControllers without navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 UIViewControllers, I would like to be able to transition back and forward but not n any particular order witout any type of navigationcontroller.

So far I have set up a method in my delegate where I can remember which view I was last on if the application is removed from memory in the mutitask bar.

it looks like this

```
if (([projectListBoolString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([installsBoolString isEqualToString:@"F"]) && ([finishinBoolString isEqualToString:@"F"])) {
        self.getProjectListViewController = [[GetProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GetProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.getProjectListViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    else if (([projectListBoolString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([installsBoolString isEqualToString:@"T"]) && ([finishinBoolString isEqualToString:@"T"])) {
        self.currentProjectListViewController = [[CurrentProjectListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentProjectListViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.currentProjectListViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
```

Whoever when I am in the application I would like to know how to jump from one view to anther making sure only 1 view is ever in memory / loaded.

Comment: Check the Class of the RootViewController. Eg: `if ([self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[CurrentProjectListViewController class]]) { // Your Code }`

Comment: @Roshit I am not sure what you mean? do you think I can use similar code when a button is pressed in a UIViewController?, if so how do I remove the old view from memeory?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(getProjectListViewController == nil)
   getProjectListViewController  = new GetProjectListViewController ();
if(viewController.view.superview!=nil){
   viewController.view.removefromSuperView();
   window.addsubview(getProjectListViewController.view);
} else {
   getProjectListViewController.view.removeFromSuperView();
   window.addsubview(viewController.view);
}
```

Add if/else-if statements as needed for more than two views. You can also continue using a navController without the interface components if you still find that easier -- there's a hidden property you can utilise.